# Access long running process status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a local gem with some functionality i moved out from main application. It primarily does data preparing for import into database

```
#importer gem's public instance method "import"
Importer::Processor.new('data.xls').prepare_for_import
```

this process can be very long-running depending on `data.xls` size

this is how i use it inside my model

```
#ProductImport model
def importing_data
  Importer::Processor.new(self.data_file).prepare_for_import
end

def insert_data_to_db
  self.class.import importing_data
end
```

and now i want to "receive" info from preparing process how it is going and write it into database for my `ProductImport` instance...

i do not want to write into current product import row directly inside gem because i want to leave gem independent

i tried to set class variable (`@@status`) inside `Importer::Processor` `prepare_for_import` method - no luck, it stays in initial state if i try to read it with async process like this

```
Importer::Processor.class_variable_get(:@@status)
```

also tried global variable `$status` and even dynamic constant setting (sorry for this =) )

```
Importer::Processor.const_set('STATUS', '1234 rows processed')
```

no luck - too

can you propose the way i can access current status of long-running process inside gem's instance method?

thank you

Comment: shouldn't you be logging for this, not writing to a database?

Comment: i want to show current process state to user and this log has to be attached to current product import process. as for me, writing to database into current product import row is most fitted option